# Symfony 6 - Translation interface

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I am trying to make my web application translatable on symfony 6.
The best would be if the translation keys could be translatable by an interface.

Do you know of a library that can do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to do some of your own research before posting a question. A simple web search on "Symfony Translation" will get you an answer.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your feedback, but I did not find what I was looking for in the search box.
I'm not asking how the translation works on symfony but I would like to know if there is a bundle or a library that allows to simply generate a translation interface in order to translate the keys by a third person and that I did not find.

Answer (score 1):

You can export translations to an external service and then re-import when translations are done. Since symfony 5.3 there is native connection with some providers likes Loco, Crowdin etc

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-translation-providers

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your answer, yes I had seen the connections in the documentation. I was looking to see if there was a free interface that we could plug into our platform in order not to reinvent the wheel if it exists. We did not find exactly what we wanted so we are going to develop our interface which will allow us to meet our needs.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look for php-translation. There is "Edit in place" feature for symfony (https://php-translation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symfony/edit-in-place.html). Maybe you can use it or extend it to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for

```
bin/console translation:extract es --dump-messages
```

While I think this answers your question, I'm not sure it's actually the right solution for translation.  Just one piece.